# Regular Expression - Want two matches get only one

Tags: regex

I'm working wih a regular expression and have some lines in javascript. My expression should deliver two matches but recognizes only one and I don't know whats the problem.

The Lines in javascript look like this:

```
if(mode==1) var adresse = "?APPNAME=CampusNet&amp;PRGNAME=ACTION&amp;ARGUMENTS=-A7uh6sBXerQwOCd8VxEMp6x0STE.YaNZDsBnBOto8YWsmwbh7FmWgYGPUHysiL9u0.jUsPVdYQAlvwCsiktBzUaCohVBnkyistIjCR77awL5xoM3WTHYox0AQs65SoHAhMXDJVr7="; else var adresse = "?APPNAME=CampusNet&amp;PRGNAME=ACTION&amp;ARGUMENTS=-AHMqmg-jXIDdylCjFLuixe..udPC2hjn6Kiioq7O41HsnnaP6ylFkQLhaUkaWKINEj4l2JqL2eBSzOpmG.b5Av2AvvUxEinUhMBTt5awdgAL4SkBEgYXGejTGUxcgPE-MfiQjefc=";
```

My expression looks like this:

```
(?<Popup>(popUp\(')|(adresse...")).*\?((?<Parameters>APPNAME=CampusNet[^>"']*["']))
```

I want to have two matches with APPNAME...... as Parameters.

[UPDATE] Like Tim Pietzcker wrote i used the greedy version and should have used the lazy version. while he wrote that i solved it myself by using .*? instead of .* in the middle so the expression looks like this:

```
(?<Popup>(popUp\(')|(adresse...")).*?\\?((?<Parameters>APPNAME=CampusNet[^>"']*["']))
```

That worked. Thanks to Tim Pietzcker

Comment: Is this C# or Java you're working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches too much - from the very first `adresse` until the very last `"` because it uses a greedy quantifier `.*`.

If you make that quantifier lazy, i. e.

```
(?<Popup>(popUp\(')|(adresse...")).*?\?((?<Parameters>APPNAME=CampusNet[^>"']*["']))
```

you get two matches.

Alternatively, if your data allows this, use a different quantifier that only matches non-space characters. This will match faster (but will fail of course if the text you're trying to match could possibly contain spaces):

```
(?<Popup>(popUp\(')|(adresse..."))\S*\?((?<Parameters>APPNAME=CampusNet[^>"']*["']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you must apply the regex with the "global" flag to find all matches. I can't really say more until I see the complete code sample you are working with.